# Why is jsp adding 16 extra <br> tags to my html?

Tags: jsp

I've got an string displaying correctly, except for the following point, where extra 
 tags are displayed:

jsp:

```
<p><%=dadesGen.getCataleg().getDescri()%></p><br>
```

dadesGen.getCataleg().getDescri() (key point):

```
(Carrer de Garcilaso, 123)<strong>.<br /><br /></strong></p><br><table style="height: 42px;" width="200">
```

And this is what I get:

[extra br tag 16 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxw04.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have table and an open `<br>` tag before of it, typo which I believe caused in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: The problem persists quitting the <br> tag before <table>.

Comment: Update on progress please.

Comment: Okay, I was SUFFERING because I didn't provide you an answer, I was TORTURED and I got ya something. Here ya go, try to eliminate: delete and bring it back every br piece and maybe possibly you will find out the problem. Very simple.